# iphone UIProgressView disappears on update

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiprogressview

Im updating a UIProgressView called “ammo”. When i update the progress the UIProgressView disappears from the UIView like its being hidden or moved behind another view.

**Code**

```
- (void)updateAmmo:(float) inputAmmo capacity:(float)inputCapacity{

   //Calculate the progress value
   float value = inputAmmo/inputCapacity;

   //If nothing has changed don’t update
   if(value != ammo.progress){
      [ammo setProgress:value];
   }
}
```

**Things I have checked**

- Checked to see if it is being hidden.
- Brought the UIProgressView to the front.
- Tried [ammo setProgress: ammo.progress-0.01]; this breaks it aswell
- Inserting a value directly works [ammo setProgress: 0.950000];
- Tried adding [ammo setNeedsDisplay];

**Logging value extracts**

- 2011-07-23 15:15:34.659 XXXXXXX[2399:207] value - 1.000000
- 2011-07-23 15:15:34.659 XXXXXXX[2399:207] value - 0.950000
- 2011-07-23 15:15:34.712 XXXXXXX[2399:207] value - 0.900000

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

if u use IB for progress creation checkout u r connect with them.

i suspect about ur value property goes to immediately to 0 or below 0

```
        - (void)updateAmmo:(float) inputAmmo capacity:(float)inputCapacity{


            float value = inputAmmo/inputCapacity;




            if(value != [ammo progress]){
                [ammo setProgress:value];
            }
        }
```

Comment: and i suspect about ur value property goes to immediately to 0

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the if statement is not the cause. I gave what you suggested above a go but it did not work. However I do not think the problem is with the if statement just detects a change in value.

Comment: The logging extracts are from the value variable which decrease by 0.05

Comment: Sorry I don’t follow? The logging shows it starts at 1.00000 then 0.950000, 0.900000 etc... Also if it reaches 0 surely the bar would be empty and not completely disappear from the screen?

Comment: if u use IB for progress creation checkout u r connect with them.